# Print PDF via dot-matrix bluetooth printer on Android

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I have developed an android application and I have generated a pdf file using `itextpdf`.

Then I want to print this pdf file on dotmatrix printer via bluetooth. For example, I have a sewoo adp-400 printer with bluetooth module.

I was able to connect from android device to printer via bluetooth, but I wasn't able to print any pdf.

Then I downloaded "Bluetooth Smart Printing" application from Google Play and I tried printing again, but unfortunately I couldn't succeed.

What can I do?
Thanks in advance for your help